# mongo/mongoid MapReduce on batch inserted documents

Tags: javascript, ruby, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

Im creating my batch and inserting it to collection using command i specified below

```
batch = []
time = 1.day.ago

(1..2000).each{ |i| a = {:name => 'invbatch2k'+i.to_s, :user_id =>  BSON::ObjectId.from_string('533956cd4d616323cf000000'), :out_id => 'out', :created_at => time, :updated_at => time, :random => '0.5' }; batch.push a; }

Invitation.collection.insert batch
```

As stated above, every single invitation record has `user_id` fields value set to `'533956cd4d616323cf000000'`

after inserting my batch with `created_at: 1.day.ago` i get:

```
2.1.1 :102 > Invitation.lte(created_at: 1.week.ago).count
 => 48
2.1.1 :103 > Invitation.lte(created_at: Date.today).count
 => 2048
```

also:

```
2.1.1 :104 > Invitation.lte(created_at: 1.week.ago).where(user_id: '533956cd4d616323cf000000').count
 => 14
2.1.1 :105 > Invitation.where(user_id: '533956cd4d616323cf000000').count
 => 2014
```

Also, I've got a map reduce which counts invitations sent by each unique User (both total and sent to unique out_id)

```
class Invitation

  [...]

  def self.get_user_invites_count
    map = %q{
      function() {
        var user_id = this.user_id;
        emit(user_id, {user_id : this.user_id, out_id: this.out_id, count: 1, countUnique: 1})
      }
    }
    reduce = %q{
      function(key, values) {
        var result = {
          user_id: key,
          count: 0,
          countUnique : 0
        };
        var values_arr = [];
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          values_arr.push(value.out_id);
          result.count += 1
        });
        var unique = values_arr.filter(function(item, i, ar){ return ar.indexOf(item) === i; });
        result.countUnique = unique.length;
        return result;
      }
    }
    map_reduce(map,reduce).out(inline: true).to_a.map{|d| d['value']} rescue []
  end
end
```

The issue is:

```
Invitation.lte(created_at: Date.today.end_of_day).get_user_invites_count
```

returns

```
[{"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('533956cd4d616323cf000000'), "count"=>49.0, "countUnique"=>2.0} ...]
```

instead of  `"count" => 2014, "countUnique" => 6.0` while:

`Invitation.lte(created_at: 1.week.ago).get_user_invites_count` returns:

```
[{"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('533956cd4d616323cf000000'), "count"=>14.0, "countUnique"=>6.0} ...]
```

Data provided by query, is accurate before inserting the batch.

I cant wrap my head around whats going on here. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that you seemed to have missed in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) seem to be the problem here:

> MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key.

And also later:

> the type of the return object must be identical to the type of the value emitted by the map function to ensure that the following operations is true:

So what you see is your reduce function is returning a signature different to the input it receives from the mapper. This is important since the reducer may not get **all** of the values for a given key in a single pass. Instead it gets some of them, "reduces" the result and that reduced output may be combined with other values for the key ( possibly also reduced ) in a further pass through the reduce function.

As a result of your fields not matching, subsequent reduce passes do not see those values and do not count towards your totals. So you need to align the signatures of the values:

```
  def self.get_user_invites_count
    map = %q{
      function() {
        var user_id = this.user_id;
        emit(user_id, {out_id: this.out_id, count: 1, countUnique: 0})
      }
    }
    reduce = %q{
      function(key, values) {
        var result = {
          out_id: null,
          count: 0,
          countUnique : 0
        };
        var values_arr = [];
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          if (value.out_id != null)
            values_arr.push(value.out_id);
          result.count += value.count;
          result.countUnique += value.countUnique;
        });
        var unique = values_arr.filter(function(item, i, ar){ return ar.indexOf(item) === i; });
        result.countUnique += unique.length;
        return result;
      }
    }
    map_reduce(map,reduce).out(inline: true).to_a.map{|d| d['value']} rescue []
  end
```

You also do not need `user_id` in the values emitted or kept as it is already the "key" value for the mapReduce. The remaining alterations consider that both "count" and "countUnique" can contain an exiting value that needs to be considered, where you were simply resetting the value to 0 on each pass.

Then of course if the "input" has already been through a "reduce" pass, then you do not need the "out_id" values to be filtered for "uniqueness" as you already have the count and that is now included. So any `null` values are not added to the array of things to count, which is also "added" to the total rather than replacing it.

So the reducer **does** get called several times. For 20 key values the input will likely not be split, which is why your sample with less input works. For pretty much anything more than that, then the "groups" of the same key values will be split up, which is how mapReduce optimizes for large data processing. As the "reduced" output will be sent back to the reducer again, you need to be mindful that you are considering the values you already sent to output in the previous pass.

Comment: you are right about the part i missed, thank you for that.
about adding user_id to values -> not all of the documents go through reduce part, and adding user_id allows me to get all the results pretty formatted by simply doing .to_a.map{|d| d['value']} :) thats how it looks now for me now: http://pastebin.com/PPEL6930 - format isnt as pretty as it was, tho it works <3

Comment: @mymlyn If you look closely at the modified emit from the mapper I have considered that not all documents may actually get passed to the reducer. If you would be expecting the "countUnique" to come out with a value of 1 and not 0 then you can add a "finalize" function to do so in cleaning up your results. Sure looks like an answer to me.